# iPhone / iPod music problem

Tags: iphone

How can I delete the music from my iPhone WITHOUT deleting it from my iPod?? 
Also, how to prevent it from just automatically loading them all back on when I sync my phone/computer. This is what happened last time, and why I don't have enough space on my phone! AGAIN.

Comment: You might have to tell us how you have iTunes and your iPhone set up. Manual syncing versus automatic syncing will make a difference on how to start. Is a viable solution to wipe the music / clear the settings for the iPhone and then start syncing it as you wish? the iPod won't care how you manage the iPhone so it can be edited out of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your iPhone to your computer. Once you open iTunes, you will see a check mark on `Sync only checked songs` in the main window for the device. This will **only** sync the songs checked in your library for that device (iPhone) and will delete the ones you don't want.

Make sure that check mark is **selected**.

In your iTunes music library, **deselect** the songs you *don't* want on your iPhone.

For your iPod, you can leave it **unchecked** and all your songs will sync.

This should solve both problems you are having.